# SQL Command for copying row values to blank matching criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working with a table with 80000 rows in mysql, more specifically accessing through phpMyAdmin.

I have found 100s of random user ids are not showing their names in the general name field but are showing it in the Shipping and billing fields. What I have below is what I would need to happen with a SQL command.

if a user_id's meta_key first_name value is blank
then copy meta_key (shipping_first_name) for user_id to meta_key named (first name) for matching user_id.

I have attached a jpg of the db so you can see the field the fields as they exist.[Picture of rows mentioned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec07l.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND
       t1.meta_key = 'first_name' AND
       t2.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name'
SET t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value
WHERE
    COALESCE(t1.meta_value, '') = ''
```

I use `COALESCE` above to treat empty string and null as the same thing in your table with regard to a missing value for the first name, as I don't know which (or both?) you are using.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I appreciate the knowledge as I am more PHP and Web coding based. 

The table was not built by me, but does contain empty strings and null values so using COALESCE is also right on.